# Update a Document in OrientDB by Removing an Item in a List

Tags: orientdb

Is it possible to remove one single item in an embedded List in a document in OrientDB? I have a document "personaldata", that contains a list of "inquiries". For example

```
{ name: "Marco", inquiries: [{date: 2014-11-22, status: "DRAFT}, {date: 2014-10-22, status: "PUBLISHED"}]}
```

Now I want to delete all inquiries in status "DRAFT". How can I accomplish this with Orient SQL?

Answer (score 4):

You can try this command

```
update personaldata remove inquiries = {"status":"DRAFT","date":"2014-11-22"}
```

Comment: I just now tried with my orientdb running on linux, and this worked like charm. Do you have any error ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It works. But only when the '@type' property is set. so this works for me: update personaldata remove inquiries = {"@type":"d","status":"DRAFT","date":"2014-11-22"}

Comment: This command removes one entry in the list. How could I remove a selection of entries, like all inquiries with status DRAFT?